# How to get a generic 3d Face model?

Tags: image-processing, 3d

I'm working on image processing that involves facial features.

Where can I get a generic 3D model of a human face? (any format is fine as long as I can manipulate the data using C or Matlab)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to make your own from a 3d face database, which may not be easy to do. This website has a good listing of public databases. http://www.face-rec.org/databases/

Answer (score -2):

A Open-Source software called MakeHuman might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Why this software? What are the advantages? Why won't you elaborate on that?

Comment: This "answer" does not really answer the question. Adding information as per jojek's questions will help us, the OP, and anyone else who happens upon this answer later.